# 'Source not Found' message on debugging testng program in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am debugging one of my testscript in testng and Eclipse is displaying a source not found window on stepping over from one breakpoint to other

Here come the code

[image: code_Image_Screenshot]

Here you can see break points in line 22 and 27.

On debugging the control transfers from the first break point to a native method and I am getting this window on Eclipse instead moving to next line.

[image: Debugger_Screenshot]

Comment: Did you use 'Step Into' on the native method call? `NativeMethodAccessorImpl` is the code that does the native method call the first few times it is used.

Comment: Hey Greg, On first time loading itself I can see these native methods in debugger. And I am using stepover instead of step into